# NullPointerException ArrayList

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I'm having trouble adding an item to the array list because of a nullpointer exception.
I"m trying to add a new account to the ArrayList which resides in the main class. So I am passing the ArrayList from the main class to the AddAcct class in order to set up the new account and add it to the list. I'm just confused as to how the variable is null when it appears as if it's initialized.

Here is the method that is calling this function. This is where the program starts. I need this ArrayList passed to the AddAcct class so that when I add a new account I can add that account to the master list of accounts.

```
//class variables
ArrayList<Account> accounts;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Window();
    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();




}

// inside a method that gets invoked on button click
if (e.getSource() == btnAddAcct){
        newAcct = new AddAcct(accounts);

    }
```

this is where I set up the ArrayList variable in the AddAcct class to receive the passed master ArrayList.

```
//class variables
ArrayList<Account> accounts;


//sets up initial window
public AddAcct(ArrayList<Account> accounts){
    super("Add Account");
    setupGUI();
    registerListeners();
    this.accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    this.accounts = accounts;

    //updateScreen();
} // end constructor
```

Here is the later method where the exception is occurring.

```
if(success){
            Account account = new Account(fName,lName);
            this.accounts.add(account);//exception is happening on this line
            String accountNum = Integer.toString(account.getAcctNum());
            lblInfo.setText(accountNum);
        }
```

For those who wanted the entire code. Here is the where the program starts.

```
package LibraryAccount;




import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import LibraryAccount.AddAcct;
import LibraryAccount.CheckInOut;


public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JButton btnAddAcct;
    JButton btnBook;
    JButton btnReport;
    AddAcct newAcct;
    CheckInOut checkInOut;
    ArrayList<Account> accounts;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
        ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();




    }
    //sets up initial window
    public Window(){
        super("Library Manager");
        setupGUI();
        registerListeners();

        //updateScreen();
    } // end constructor

    public void setupGUI(){

        JPanel pnlControls = new JPanel();
        btnAddAcct = new JButton("Add Account");
        btnBook = new JButton("Check out/in book");
        btnReport = new JButton("Reports");


        //add components to Panels



        pnlControls.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pnlControls.add(btnAddAcct);
        pnlControls.add(btnBook);
        pnlControls.add(btnReport);


        //set up layout
        Container mainPanel = this.getContentPane();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));

        mainPanel.add(pnlControls);


        this.setSize(500, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    } // end setup

    public void registerListeners(){


        btnAddAcct.addActionListener(this);
        btnBook.addActionListener(this);
        btnReport.addActionListener(this);


    } // end registerListeners

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        //check all button presses for action


      //back button
        if (e.getSource() == btnAddAcct){
            newAcct = new AddAcct(accounts);

        } 
        //checkout/in book
        else if(e.getSource() ==btnBook){
            checkInOut = new CheckInOut();
        }

        //report pressed
        else if(e.getSource() == btnReport){

        }


        else {


        } // end if


    } // end actionPerformed

}
```

Here is the AddAcct class

```
package LibraryAccount;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class AddAcct extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JButton btnAddAcct;
    JLabel lblAddress;
    JLabel lblCity;
    JLabel lblZip;
    JLabel lblState;
    JLabel lblFName;
    JLabel lblLName;
    JLabel lblInfo;
    JTextArea txtFName;
    JTextArea txtLName;
    JTextArea txtAddress;
    JTextArea txtCity;
    JTextArea txtZip;
    JTextArea txtState;
    ArrayList<Account> accounts;







    //sets up initial window
    public AddAcct(ArrayList<Account> accounts){
        super("Add Account");
        setupGUI();
        registerListeners();
        this.accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
        this.accounts = accounts;

        //updateScreen();
    } // end constructor

    public void setupGUI(){

        JPanel pnlControls = new JPanel();
        btnAddAcct = new JButton("Add Account");
        lblAddress = new JLabel("Address");
        lblCity = new JLabel("City");
        lblZip = new JLabel("Zip");
        lblState = new JLabel("State");
        lblFName = new JLabel("First Name");
        lblLName = new JLabel("Last Name");
        lblInfo = new JLabel("");
        txtFName = new JTextArea(30,1);
        txtLName = new JTextArea(30,1);
        txtAddress = new JTextArea(30,1);
        txtCity = new JTextArea(30,1);
        txtZip = new JTextArea(30,1);
        txtState = new JTextArea(30,1);







        //add components to Panels

        pnlControls.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        pnlControls.add(lblInfo);
        pnlControls.add(lblFName);
        pnlControls.add(txtFName);
        pnlControls.add(lblLName);
        pnlControls.add(txtLName);
        pnlControls.add(lblAddress);
        pnlControls.add(txtAddress);
        pnlControls.add(lblCity);
        pnlControls.add(txtCity);
        pnlControls.add(lblZip);
        pnlControls.add(txtZip);
        pnlControls.add(lblState);
        pnlControls.add(txtState);
        pnlControls.add(btnAddAcct);

        //set up layout
        Container mainPanel = this.getContentPane();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));

        mainPanel.add(pnlControls);

        this.setSize(500, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);


    } // end setup

    public void registerListeners(){


        btnAddAcct.addActionListener(this);



    } // end registerListeners

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        //check all button presses for action


      //back button
        if (e.getSource() == btnAddAcct){
            boolean success = true;
            int zip;
            String fName = "";
            String lName ="";
            String address;
            String city;
            String state;
            try{
                zip = Integer.parseInt(txtZip.getText());
                fName = txtFName.getText();
                lName = txtLName.getText();
                address = txtAddress.getText();
                city = txtCity.getText();
                state = txtState.getText();


            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e1){
                lblInfo.setText("Please enter number for zip");
                success = false;
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e1){
                lblInfo.setText("All fields required");
                success = false;
            }
            if(success){
                Account account = new Account(fName,lName);
                this.accounts.add(account);
                String accountNum = Integer.toString(account.getAcctNum());
                lblInfo.setText(accountNum);
            }


        } 


        else {


        } // end if


    } // end actionPerformed

}
```

Comment: Please post all the code. It's easier to edit it and tell you which lines are screwed up.

Comment: Never mind. I just realized what happened. I didn't intilize the accounts in the main starting class. I made an instance inside the public static void main(String[] args)  and thought it was the same as the class level variable.

Comment: I suggest that you just delete the Question then.

Answer (score 0):

In the last chunk of code you posted, `accounts` is null. You give null to AddAcct's constructor (first piece of code).

In the first piece of code you set the class variable to a new ArrayList, then on the very next line you set it to the null that was passed from the last chunk of code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these two line:

```
this.accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
this.accounts = accounts;
```

Your assign this.accounts to a new ArrayList but right after that your re-assign it to the accounts argument. The ArrayList you created will just be garbage-collected at some point and since you don't actually create a list in the calling code, your code throws a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just realized what happened. I didn't intilize the accounts in the main starting class. I made an instance inside the public static void main(String[] args) and thought it was the same as the class level variable